# Add multiple classes to element with @if statement

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a following problem. I am checking if arrays are empty and if they are i am hiding specific elements in table. This implementation adds only 1 class but is there a way to add multiple without using javascript?

```
<table @if(empty($a)) class="hide_a"@endif
    @if(empty($aa)) class="hide_aa"@endif
    @if(empty($aaa)) class="hide_aaa"@endif>
```

Comment: Cannot use javascript because dompdf does not support it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is, that a html element can only have one `class` attribute. 
Simply check the value inside the class attribute

```html
<table class="{{ empty($a) ? 'hide_a' : '' }} {{ empty($aa) ? 'hide_aa' : '' }} {{ empty($aaa) ? 'hide_aaa' : '' }}">
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it as below.

```
    <table class="@if(empty($a)) hide_a @endif 
@if(empty($aa)) hide_aa @endif 
@if(empty($aaa)) hide_aaa @endif">
```

Comment: Do not use a ternary operator for this. when you use a ternary operator it is the case where you check if..else.. and you don't need else part.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <table class="@if(empty($a))  hide_a @endif 
       @if(empty($aa)) hide_aa @endif 
       @if(empty($aaa)) hide_aaa @endif">
```